# Debugging Step By Step Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Java {

    public static int numberOfLoops;
    public static int numberOfIterations;
    public static int[] loops;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("N = ");
        numberOfLoops = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("K = ");
        numberOfIterations = input.nextInt();

        input.close();

        loops = new int[numberOfLoops];
        System.out.println("main START");
        nestedLoops(0);
        System.out.println("main END");
    }

    public static void nestedLoops(int currentLoop) {
        System.out.println("nestedLoops");
        System.out.println("currentLoop " + currentLoop);
        if (currentLoop == numberOfLoops) {
            printLoops();
            return;
        }

        for (int counter = 1; counter <= numberOfIterations; counter++) {
            System.out.println("nestedLoops in LOOP");
            System.out.println("currentLoop in LOOP " + currentLoop);
            loops[currentLoop] = counter;
            nestedLoops(currentLoop + 1);

        }
    }

    public static void printLoops() {
        System.out.println("printLoops");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLoops; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d", loops[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Hi all. I'm new here and this is my first post.

My question is:

If i put for N = 2 and K = 4 why after first return currentLoop continue with 1 we pass to the method 0 ?

Thanks , Nikola

Comment: Please be more explicit about what you're asking.  I.e. state what you are expecting to happen where, and then tell us what you think actually happened and why that doesn't match your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question completely..but

When you call

```
nestedLoops(0);
```

You go into the nestedLoops function with currentLoop = 0.
Within this function, you call

```
nestedLoops(currentLoop + 1);
```

And that's why you get a

```
nestedLoop(1)
```

called while you're in your

```
nestedLoop(0)
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

---

Edited:

When

```
nestedLoops(1)
```

is called, we call

```
nestedLoops(2)
```

right? 
When we compare currentLoop and numberOfLoops inside of nestedLoops(2), they are both 2,
so we go into

```
printLoops();
```

Once printLoops is done, we return into

```
nestedLoops(2)
```

However, after printLoops(), we have a

```
return;
```

Therefore, we return out of

nestedLoops(2)
and we come back into

```
nestedLoops(1)
```

where nestedLoops(2) was called from.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for fast answer!
I don't understand when we go to the bottom of recursion

 if (currentLoop (2) == (2) numberOfLoops) {
    printLoops();
    return;
 }

and we are back to the for loop and variable currentLoop is 1

Comment: @user2498774 if this post answered your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the green check mark, so viewers will know that this problem has been solved. :-)